# How to list events by category and month with plugin Event Organiser?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-event-organiser

I need to display a list of events by category and month. For example I need to list all the Mountain Bike events in July.

Comment: Show us what you have tried already and where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the plug-in provided function `eo_get_events()`. This is essentially a wrapper for [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), and so is intended for 'secondary' loops.

The plug-in specific arguments can also be given to a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object - in case you wanted to modify the main loop. (**Related:** [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762) )

```
$events = eo_get_events(array(
   'tax_query'=>array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'event-category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'mountain-bike'
      )
    )
   'event_start_after'=>'2012-07-01',
   'event_start_before'=>'2012-07-30',
  ))
```

*assuming mountain-bike is the slug of your category term*

The only plug-in specific arguments here are `event_start_after` and `event_start_before` which accept a date string in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format (as above, or a relative date such as `+1 week` or `third Thursday of this month` - please note available relative dates will depend on your php version).

There are also `event_end_after` and `event_end_before` arguments available. All of these can be used in a `WP_Query` object too.

Please note `eo_get_events()` sets some defaults ([See documentation](http://www.harriswebsolutions.co.uk/event-organiser/documentation/function-reference/eo_get_events/)).

Return is an array of post objects (of 'event' post type). [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762) shows how to display the returned posts (see `get_posts()` section).